# Ormlite: Is it possible to ignore base class field from the sub class?

Tags: android, ormlite

```
Class A{
    @DatabaseField(generatedId=true, columnName=ID_FIELD_NAME)
    private int id:
    @DatabaseField
    private C cfield;
}


@DatabaseTable(tableName="B class")
Class B extends A{
    ...
    ...
}
```

Is it possible to say to class B to ignore the C field from the base class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
private C cfield;
```

Will be ignored by ORMLite by default.

The reason is there is no annotation given for the cfield. If you don't specify annotation `@DatabaseField` for an attribute, that will be ignored.

---

Visibility of attributes can do the trick. Like

```
Class A {
    @DatabaseField(generatedId=true, columnName=ID_FIELD_NAME)
    protected int id; // Set public or protected for sharable attributes
    @DatabaseField
    private C cfield; // Set private which you want to ignore from Child class
}
```

Comment: Sorry it was my mistake, i forgot to put the databasefield annotation. I want it for some classes and want to avoid for others. Is this possible?

Comment: Yes. I think visiblity can do the trick. Like declare the field as protected which you want to access into class B, and declare the field as private which you want to ignore into class B.

Comment: Ok, but imagine i have a class D that also extends A  and i want the field cfield?

Comment: Then this is not possible from ORMLite. ORMLite doesn't give any annotation or way to ignore some fields. So you have to design your classes as per your situation.

Comment: Ok, also my base class has a the id field has private and i thought it was working because it creates the auto increment field. All my table classes extend that base class that has the private int id field. But what you're saying seems to go against this. OR am i wrong?

Comment: Visibility of the fields will not help with this @Maxrunner.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to say to class B to ignore the C field from the base class?

Sorry but no.  ORMLite by default investigates all base class fields and will find the fields that have annotations -- even if marked as `private`.